# add class to closest ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add a class to the following < ul > for a h3-element which contains the string "Informationen".

That's how the html-output looks like now:

```
<h3>Informationen</h3>
<ul>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</li>
<li>Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes</li>
<li>Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu</li>
</ul>
```

I want to achieve the code is like this:

```
<h3>Informationen</h3>
<ul class"normal">
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</li>
<li>Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes</li>
<li>Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu</li>
</ul>
```

I have several h3-elements with different strings, so I'm grabbing the correct one with this script:

```
$('h3').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var text = $this.html();
    if (text == 'Informationen'){
    alert(text);
    };
});
```

Now the alert shows me the string "Informationen" when an Element with this text/string is found.

To now add a class to the closest/next ul I tried this:

```
$('h3').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var text = $this.html();
    if (text == 'Informationen'){
    //alert(text);
    $this.closest('ul').addClass('normal');
    };
});
```

But this didn't work, like the following script didn't work too:

```
$('h3').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var text = $this.html();
    if (text == 'Informationen'){
    //alert(text);
    $(this).closest('ul').addClass('normal');
    };
});
```

Here's a fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/JNtw2/1/

Can anyone point me to a solution for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`closest()` gets the closest matching parent element, you're looking for `next()` as the UL comes right after the H3

```
$('h3').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var text = $this.html();
    if (text == 'Informationen'){

        $this.next('ul').addClass('normal');

    };
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JNtw2/3/)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the closest() method you need to use the next() method.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest you this instead?

Note: This assumes Informationen will not be contained within a sentence in another h3.

```
$('h3:contains(Informationen)').next().addClass('normal');
```

Also note that you do not have to pass a sector to `next` if you know that every `h3` tag is followed by a `ul` tag.